# Assignee in Jira via REST API (php)

Tags: php, rest, api, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to assignee issue to another person.

I have the code, but it doesn't work. Why? Who can help me?

May some parameter is wrong?

If I enter to the JIRA via this login and pass I can change assigneer

```
    function send_to_jira($url, $data) {

    $username = 'bot@user.name';
    $password = 'bot_password';

    $curl = curl_init();
    $headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}

        $data = array(
            "fileds" => array(
                "assignee" => array("name" => "newusername")
            ),
        );
        $url = 'https://site/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE';
        $result = send_to_jira($url, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just copied your code, then there is a typo in the `$data` object you're sending: you have to write `fields` instead of `fileds`.
Alternatively, you can also use the `issue/<issue>/assignee` endpoint. See docs for [server](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.13.0/#api/2/issue-assign) or [cloud](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-api-2-issue-issueIdOrKey-assignee-put).

As an addition, if you are making this call to a Jira Cloud REST API, please take care about the deprecation notices regarding [basic authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/) and [usernames](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-user-privacy-api-migration-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
   ("name" = "newusername")
```

use

```
("accountId" = "5b109f2e9xxxb51b54dc274d")
```